# ObservableCollection Fires Event On Completed

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I work on a WPF project build in MVVM architecture.
My ViewModel class contains `ObservableCollection` of `SentenceVM` class which is  also a ViewModel class (implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

This `ObservableCollection` bound to a DataGrid and I would like to allow adding new records to the collection via the DataGrid build in function.

```
ObservableCollection<SentenceVM> observe = new ObservableCollection<SentenceVM>()
```

The problem is that the `CollectionChanged` event fires at the beginning of the adding row procedure. Thus, I don't know when to refer to the database to submit the new data.

I need this event to be fired when the user has finished adding the new data, not at the beginning.

I know it could be done by generating a command which executes on END inserting or on Enter key but i'm looking for a practical way to do so with this `ObservableCollection`.

Thank you !

Comment: the collectionchanged event will fire whenever a new item is added to the collection (or removed), which is why you are getting the event at the beginning. what determines when the user is finished adding data?

Comment: Yes I know that, but i'm looking for a way to get notified (at the VM class) when the user has finished adding the data.

Comment: right, but the user can add data anytime. what type of mechanism would you use to determine that the user has finished? for example, you would need something like a "timer" that will fire an "addingfinished" event if there is no data being added after 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out there is no way to do so via `ObservableCollection`. The only way to do so in practical way is to define an 'EventToCommand' trigger which executes on `CellEditEnding` event and execute the bounded command, like that:

1) Define the trigger class which inherits from the `TriggerAction` class and define the invoke method:

```
public class EventToCommandTrigger : TriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
```

2) Define the ICommand (dependency property) to bound to:

```
public ICommand CommandToExecute
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandToExecuteProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandToExecuteProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandToExecuteProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandToExecute", typeof(ICommand), typeof(EventToCommandTrigger), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
```

3) Implement the abstract Invoke method like that:

```
protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
{
    if (CommandToExecute == null)
        return;
    if (CommandToExecute.CanExecute(parameter))
        CommandToExecute.Execute(parameter);
}
```

4) Then in the xaml code, connect the `CellEditEnding` event to the above trigger, like that:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
        <triggers:EventToCommandTrigger CommandToExecute="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: yup, this is a good approach too. initially, i wasn't sure how the data was being added, but 'celledit' works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the CollectionChanged event fires at the beginning of the adding row procedure. Thus, I don't know when to refer to the database to submit the new data.

In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with inserting the data into the database inside the `CollectionChanged` event. In fact, the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` gives you everything you need in order to perform this action.

Consider looking at `e.NewItems`, and `e.OldItems`. The `NewItems` is the data that is being inserted into the collection, you can simply iterate through this list and act accordingly.